# What to do with questions from here that have already been answered in another SE site?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, unanswered-questions

Frequently, I see *unanswered* questions from this site that has been previously asked in another SE site (mostly [SO](http://stackoverflow.com)) and this one has an answer that have worked for the OP.

Should I copy and paste the answer here, *and improve the information according for the case*?

Or anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote it, link to it and give original credit as far as you can... Just as you would to any resource. Note that if you're copying from an SE site, you must do this [as part of the license](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

If you add *nothing*, consider setting your answer as a community wiki. This means you won't get any rep but displays good manners and fine breeding. Chivalry and all that nonsense.

Comment: Please note that [the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) is CC-BY-SA 3.0 now (see the bottom of any page), even though the attribution requirements/guidelines document still refers to version 2.5. (So for people reading the actual license, the correct version is the one linked to at the bottom of the page containing the content you're interested in copying.)

Comment: Oh, the license stuff is something good to have in mind. And the CW is a good advice.